# detect key pressed without bge

Tags: scripting, interface

I managed to determine, if a specific key is pressed.
Is there a way how to determine if any key is pressed?

```
 if event.type == 'A':
```

I tried with

```
  if event.type == 'NOTHING':
```

, but unfortunately in vain.

Is it possible?

Answer (score -1):

Writing the question has already helped.

```
if event.value = 'PRESS':
```